# how to count the number of records selected through a checkbox

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

i want a vf page that has the account records along with a checkbox i want a counter field on VF page that shows the no. of records selected

Answer (score 1):

You could either make a counter in your controller and use something like this:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selectedAccountMap[c.Account.Id]}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!selectAccount}" rerender="pbAccountList">
        <apex:param name="selectedAccountMap[c.Account.Id]" value="{!selectedAccountMap[c.Account.Id]}" />
    </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:inputCheckbox>
```

where the selectAccount() action will be called everytime this checkbox has changed
or use javascript to select and count all checked checkboxes

Comment: Regarding the JavaScript variant: if you use some form of pagination, be aware that the selections on other pages are not taken into account!

Comment: $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() { $('div#checked-count').text($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length + {!selectedOnOtherPages}) }) :)

Answer (score 1):

From a user-experience point of view, I'd go with jQuery. If you count them via the controller, then there will be an AJAX call to update the count and that will have a delay on it.

So, I'd include jQuery on the page as a static resource, then use something like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() { $('div#checked-count').text($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) })
```

...which would write the number of checked boxes into a div with the id checked-count.

Comment: can't we use simple apex or vf tags for this req

Comment: how to do the first solution that include ajax

Comment: As nohero has answered, you can use just vf and apex. His code suggestion looks good. Whether to do that or jQuery is a matter of preference. I prefer the jQuery version as it is just one line of code and has no delays associated with calling your apex controller.